# Coroutine is not working fine - Unity [C#]

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, vuforia, coroutine

i'm using Unity to track some image target (ARCamera - Vuforia) and everything works fine. I've inserted some 2D sprites on the image target etc... but now i don't want to show all the targets as soon as the image target is found, so i went to **DefaultTrackableEventHandler.cs** and instantiated my custom class **Example** like this:

```
 #region PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

 private TrackableBehaviour mTrackableBehaviour;

 #endregion // PRIVATE_MEMBER_VARIABLES

 public Example mainClass;
```

...

```
private void OnTrackingFound()
    {
    ...
        Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");

        mainClass = new Example();
        mainClass.OnTrackableFound(); // Public method on 'Example' Class
    }
```

Now on my Example class:

public class Example : MonoBehaviour {

```
public SpriteRenderer forYou;
public SpriteRenderer map;

public Example () {}

private bool isInTransition = false;
private float transition = 1;
private bool isShowing = false;
private float duration = 0;

void Start()
{
    forYou = new SpriteRenderer();
    map = new SpriteRenderer();
}

public void OnTrackableFound() {
    StartCoroutine(FadeCoroutine());
}

private IEnumerator FadeCoroutine() {
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(1);
    Fade(true, .1f);
}

public void OnTrackableLost() {}

public void Fade (bool showing, float duration)
{
    isShowing = showing;
    isInTransition = true;
    this.duration = duration;
    transition = (isShowing) ? 0 : 1;
}

void Update ()
{
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown (0)) {
        Fade (true, .1f);
    }
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonUp (0)) {
        Fade (false, .1f);
    }


    if (!isInTransition) {
        return;
    }

    transition += (isShowing) ? Time.deltaTime * (1 / duration) : -Time.deltaTime * (1 / duration);
    forYou.color = Color.Lerp (Color.white, new Color (1, 1, 1, 0), transition);
    map.color = Color.Lerp (Color.white, new Color (1, 1, 1, 0), transition);

    if (transition > 1 || transition < 0) {
        isInTransition = false;
    }
}
```

}
Sorry for the amount of code, but basically this is just for fading in/out some sprites. I want to yield as soon as my OnTrackingFound is called at Example class  and after idk .5 seconds fade in some of my sprites.

Thank you!

## EDIT - SOLVED

So, to attach a script to a game object it must inherit from Monobehaviour but than it cannot be instantiated so what i did was:
I needed the OnTrackingFound() from the DefaultTrackerHandler... so i coded everything on that class [i know it's far from the best solution but...] instead of instantiate another script because as i said it wouldn't be possible to attach it to a game object since it couldn't inherit from Monobehaviour. With public game objects, i attached everything directly from this class that also inherits from Monobehvr. If you instantiate a script that inherits monobehv it will be null. Thanks everyone!

Comment: Just a comment - The OnTrackableFound() is being called normally on my Example class, but the StartCoroutine inside it is never called.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue with your code is that you try to instantiate component `Example` that derives from `MonoBehaviour` calling constructor with `new` keyword.

Never do this.

All components in Unity3D Engine needs to be added to existing `GameObject` with `GameObject.AddComponent<T>()`

So what you need to do is:

```
private void OnTrackingFound()
{
    ...
    Debug.Log("Trackable " + mTrackableBehaviour.TrackableName + " found");

    // create new GameObject and add component
    mainClass = new GameObject("MyNewGameobject").AddComponent<Example>();
    mainClass.OnTrackableFound(); // Public method on 'Example' Class
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are calling `mainClass = new Example();` every time a new target is tracked. This will create a new object even-though there might be an existing objects. I don't believe you want this.

Instead try call the `GameObject gobj = GameObject.Find()` (because the GameObject already exists right?) function to get the existing GameObject that the script is attached to. Then do a `gobj.GetComponent<Example>(). OnTrackableFound()` to call the event on the GameObject. Hope that helps.

Comment: Can i do this from a non mono-behaviour script? Such as DefaultTracker... Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I've answered a [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/137209/causing-update-loop-with-coroutine-unity/137216#137216) which needs a delay like this in gamedev.

Basically you will increment a `float` value overtime, and when desired amount of time passed you will fade the sprite.

Pseudo:

```
float counter;
bool isFadeReady = false;
void Update ()
{
   if (OnTrackingFound) 
   {

    isFadeReady = true;
   }

   if (isFadeReady == true) 
   {
    counter +=0.1f;  //change the value for increase speed
   }


   if(counter>=1.0f) //change the value for desired time
   {
   //Fade your sprite here
   isFadeReady = false;
   }

}
```

Hope this helps! Cheers!